# How to fetch browser console errors into your project terminal output? in javascript using postAPI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, frontend

I want to fetch browser console errors into my localhost terminal .for example (Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT )

I was using Event Listener but when I see my console there were no attributes such as message ,type , line number. ,filename . Is there any other way of doing this

[console browser no attribute of evt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcwZZ.png)

```
window.addEventListener("error", handleError, true);

function handleError(evt) {
    //console.log(evt,"abc")
    let reqObj = {
        method: "post",
        url: /mypostrequest,
        data: {
            eventmessage: evt.message ? evt.message : evt.type,
            lineno: evt.lineno ? evt.lineno : "",
            filename: evt.filename ? evt.filename : "",
        },
    };
    Mck.ajaxCall(reqObj)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            return (res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            Mck.errorPopup("Something went wrong, please try again");
        });
}
```

I am trying to post the errors to my API endpoint

```
app.post('/mypostrequest', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Data======================================");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200);
    res.end();
})
```

[Screenshot of VSCODE terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwAvA.png)